# Update manager: "Could not download all repository indices"

Tags: update-manager

```
Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/pmcenery/ppa/ubuntu/dists/olivia/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/pmcenery/ppa/ubuntu/dists/olivia/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
Failed to fetch gzip:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_raring_universe_binary-amd64_Packages  Hash Sum mismatch
Failed to fetch gzip:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_raring_universe_binary-i386_Packages  Hash Sum mismatch
Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Answer (score 4):

Several possibilities:

1. Your internet connection is spotty or went down during the update.
2. The repository's internet connection is down.
3. The You've added repositories that are no longer maintained.

You can try

a) deselecting the repositories that are causing you trouble.

b) selecting a different location for the main Ubuntu repositories.

c) a combination of a and b.

I'd try (c). In dash, type `Software Updates` and click on it.

[image: Select Server]

[image: Other Sources]