# Synaptic: Could not download all repository indices

Tags: apt, package-management, synaptic

I've been trying on and off to fix this and I have come to the point where I need to ask for help. The last thing I did was visit here ([Update manager: "Could not download all repository indices"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/311884/update-manager-could-not-download-all-repository-indexes))... also [this Ubuntu Forums post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2236500)

I've been getting this for reasons:

```
W:Failed to fetch http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release  
 Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-386/Packages' in Release file 
 (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)
W:Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release  
 Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-386/Packages' in Release file 
 (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)
W:Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/Release
  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-386/Packages' in Release file 
  (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)
W:Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/Release
 Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-386/Packages' in Release file 
 (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)
E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

The last link deals with the i386 arch which I added, I believe, so I could use the Android SDK with Eclipse. I started to install things outside of Synaptic but MySQL Server 5.5 did me in and I need this to test out ideas for Android app development. I know through Synaptic it will be a breeze if I can get it running. (And future package management)

`/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main restricted universe multiverse

###### Ubuntu Update Repos
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates main restricted universe multiverse

###### Ubuntu Extras Repo
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
```

There are no entries in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`

Wish I could be more helpful with the timeframes but I have no clue what I did to make it happen or when exactly it happened. My system worked fine for some time and has been like this for some time.

Answer (score 1):

Searching for "add i386 repositories", I stumbled across the suggestion to specify an architecture in the `sources.list` file to prevent these warnings.

I placed `[arch=amd64]` after the word `deb` on each line of the file.

I did not add anything to the `deb-src` lines.

This solved the problem.